# Method for storing access rights of user

Tags: java, acl, user-permissions

I'm creating an application in Java (& using Mysql as DBMS).
My app. has users and each user can be permitted or not permitted for each feature of app. 
there are 8 different static permissions.
How can I store these permissions for each user?
Is it a good idea to store it like Unix file mode bits (e.g. 0775)?

Thanks

Comment: You need to consider your use case before asking this question. What are the requirements - security, performance, resilience etc.

Comment: I think this is a valid questions providing enough context to deserve a good answer (or two)... from what I understood, this is not about roles, this is about row-level permissions, like "user may change this entity", "member of group may add sub-entity" and so on.
I am tempted to think that the Unix bits approach is a good idea, but I see one drawback: the semantics of the permissions string may never change, e.g. the second digit from the right always means "group permissions" with a fixed set of possible values. Upvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 of the many many approaches:

1) database : define roles like admin, manager etc. so that they can have viewing, writing roles. the tables will contain the users and the roles assigned to them.

2) xml files for storing the names and the roles. (Tomcat is a good example. u can store the roles in conf.xml)

3) if u want to chuck out db and xml.. simple bit operations can also help u. 
http://vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html

this site explains how to use permissions using bit operations.

Answer (score 2):

You can store in values in bit format like

for Permission 1 you can store value as 00000001
For Permission 2 you can store value as 00000010

and so on

And you use bitwise And(`&`) operation for mapping or validating the permissions of the users

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in the database.

### Users_Table

ID

FIRSTNAME

LASTNAME

### Users_RIGHTS

USER_ID

RIGHT_ID

### RIGHTS_TALBE

ID

NAME